# Log4j2 - Spring Test logger not found

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

My hierarchy is this way

```
App -> src -> main -> resources -> log4j.xml
App -> src -> test -> test-resources -> log4j.xml
```

And My Test class runs with this configuration

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:**/beans-common.xml", "classpath:/beans.xml", "classpath:/dao.xml",
    "classpath:/service-config.xml"})
```

Any idea, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please rename the config file to `log4j2.xml` or `log4j2-test.xml`.
Log4j2 will find those files if they are in the classpath. (It will look for the test one first.)

Your config files are named `log4j.xml` (they're missing the '2').